# Write Codec for embedded documents in mongodb-java-driver

Tags: java, mongodb, bson, mongo-java-driver

I am using mongo-java-driver in my application to read and write data to mongodb.

I have classes like this -

```
public A{
    private String a;
    //Getters & Setters
}

public class B{
    private String b;
    private List<A> a;
    //Getters & Setters
}

public class C{
    private String c;
    private B b;
    //Getters & Setters
}
```

I have created Codec for the classes C like this -

```
public class CCodec implements Codec<C> {

    private Codec<Document> documentCodec;

    public CCodec(CodecRegistry registry) {
        documentCodec = registry.get(Document.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void encode(BsonWriter writer, C c, EncoderContext context)     {
        Document document = new Document();
        document.put("c",c.getC());
        document.put("b",c.getB());
        documentCodec.encode(writer, document, context);
    }
}
```

Codec for class B -

```
public class BCodec implements Codec<B> {

        private Codec<Document> documentCodec;

        public CCodec(CodecRegistry registry) {
            documentCodec = registry.get(Document.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void encode(BsonWriter writer, B b, EncoderContext context)     {
            writer.writeStartDocument();
            writer.writeString("b",b.getB());
            //How to encode A Here
            writer.writeEndDocument();
        }
    }
```

I can not do encoding in BCodec as i did for CCodec because when i say

```
Document document = new Document();
```

It creates a new document but i wan't to have it embedded in Document C.

Now the question is how do i encode field a of type List in B class?
See encode method of BCodec class.
Needless to say i have added all the Codec in CodecProvider.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [`DocumentCodec.encode`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/org/bson/codecs/DocumentCodec.html#encode-org.bson.BsonWriter-org.bson.Document-org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext-) method as follows -

```
@Override
public void encode(BsonWriter writer, B b, EncoderContext context) {
    org.bson.Document bsonDocument = new org.bson.Document();
    List<A> a = B.getA();
    bsonDocument.put("a", a);
    ...
    documentCodec.encode(writer, bsonDocument, encoderContext);
}
```

and as you **`decode`** :

```
@Override
public B decode(BsonReader reader, DecoderContext decoderContext) {
    org.bson.Document bsonDocument = documentCodec.decode(reader, decoderContext);
    B b = new B();
    b.setA((List)bsonDocument.getString("a"));
    ...
    return b;
}
```

Comment: How is it different from one i have written above?

Comment: @RaviKumar **//How to encode A Here** in your code is what has been answered.  *how do i encode field a of type List in B class?* is where I have casted the encoded `A` to a List while decoding the `B`.